# Boost Beast WebSockets with several indeterminate writes per read

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, beast

Using boost/beast websockets in C++

I've read up on the issues with beast websockets not supporting non-blocking reads, and the fact that there's no way to check if data is available, and that doing reads and writes in separate threads is probably not thread safe.

The issue I have, then, is figuring out the correct approach to this problem:

The IBM Watson speech-to-text WebSockets API allows you to send chunks of audio data as they become available (or in pieces from an existing file.) However, you do not get text replies for each chunk.

Instead, you keep sending it audio data until it recognizes a pause or an end of utterance, and then it finally sends back some results.

In other words, you may have to do several writes before a read will return anything, and there's no way to predict how many writes you will have to do.

Without a non-blocking read function, and without putting the blocking read in a separate thread, how do I keep sending data and then only retrieving results when they're available?

Answer (score 3):

Don't confuse the lack of thread safety with a lack of full-duplex capability. You can call `async_read` and then follow it with a call to `async_write`. This will result in two "pending" asynchronous operations. The write operation will complete shortly afterwards, and the read operation will remain pending until a message is received.

Asio's asynchronous model is "reactive." That means that your completion handler gets called when something happens. You don't "check to see if data is available." Beast doesn't reinvent the wheel here, it adopts the asynchronous model of Asio. If you understand how to write asynchronous network programs with Asio, this knowledge will transfer over to Beast.

Comment: An example will be most beneficial for BOOST newbies.